# PHP Using function_exists() with arguments

Tags: php

I like experimenting with PHP. I made my own abbreviated MVC and am having fun with it.  this all works (separating display and logic) and allows me to make themes to boot. Uses the KISS method. So no MVC/OOP answers please. Just a personal project.

In the code below, you can see I am able to route all my functions. however I just noticed an odd thing I am not sure of. Most of my pages are small, and rarely have arguments due to simplicity. So I made a larger app (game) which of course needs arguments, this is where I got bugs so to speak :-)

when using this method of calling functions, it works perfect, until I send an argument. then it gives me the

> *Too few arguments to function validate(), 0 passed*

Which is not true.

So, I understand WHY this does not work, as $function is a variable and not an actual function, so it would be similar to saying $variable($argument) which is illegal.

So as long as there are no arguments, it works.

Looking at the code, you can see what I am trying to accomplish(if possible), how can this be done? If at all.
EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION

```
 $view = 'default';
    if (isset($url[0])) $view         = $url[0];`code`
    if (isset($url[1])) $function     = $url[1];
    if (isset($url[2])) $arg         = $url[2];
    if (isset($url[3])) $arg2        = $url[3];    // used for 2 arguments`


if(!empty($function) && function_exists($function)){
        switch(true){
            // add your case logic for your hight arg count down to here
            case(!empty($arg) && !empty($arg2)) : $function($arg,$arg2);  break; // BOTH arg not empty
            case(!empty($arg) && empty($arg2))  : $function($arg);        break; // FIRST arg only
            case(empty($arg) && empty($arg2))   : $function();            break; // BOTH arg EMPTY
            case(empty($arg) &&
                 empty($arg2) &&
                 isset($_POST))                  :$function("hello world");       break; // BOTH arg EMPTY POST set
        }
    }
```

No jquery, I prefer pure js
Again, this is just a personal project exploring some of the features of PHP.

Can any of you pro's help me have fun with this?
Thanks!

special thanks to @Imaginaroom pointed me in the right direction:

Here is the updated code:

```
 if(isset($function) && function_exists($function)){
        if(isset($_POST)) {
            call_user_func($function, $_POST);
        }else{
            call_user_func_array($function, array($arg, $arg2));
        }
```

Thanks again to the rest of you as well. It seemed after I corrected this, many has a similar idea. Great minds!!

While it will need some clean up. this now works as should. And, more importantly, it allowed me to kill a lot of redundant code.

Comment: How your `$function` looks like? `!empty($function)` is actually calling your function and if it requires arguments, PHP warns you about that. Also `function_exists` excepts string as argument, not function itself.

Comment: The code you posted works fine, `$function($arg)` is perfectly valid PHP syntax to call a function: https://3v4l.org/AOtgv

Comment: As @Justinas told you, function_exists accepts only strings (name of function) to check. Your first condition should be replaced with just is_callable($function).

Comment: not sure what you mean "how your $function looks like"?

Comment: @axiac I thought so too, so why the too few arguments? error

Comment: From the error message *"Too few arguments to function validate(), 0 passed"* it seems `$function == 'validate'` and `$arg` and `$arg2` are empty. Please note that the PHP function [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) also considers the number `0` and the string `"0"` as empty values.

Comment: to those commenting about function_exists accepting strings only, I understand that, I think you need this part - I edited my OP doesnt show well in a coment

Comment: @AXIAC yup, and thus why I forced a 'hellow world' to make a argument (yes post exists during testing), but it can't see the hello world

Comment: The last `case` condition is not evaluated when the previous case condition (`empty($arg) && empty($arg2)`) is `true` and it evaluates to `false` when the previous condition is also `false`. The call to `$function("hello world")` is dead code; it is never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by my opinion, `empty($function)` could case the problem if it tries to call the callable assigned to variable `$function` and that's why it fails (haven't tested it).

But still, function_exists accepts only string as a parameter, which should represent a function name to check if it exists (obviously). So if your variable `$function` is a name of function then you cannot use it like `$function($arg, $arg2)` instead you need to look into [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function.
On the other hand, if you assigned a function itself to variable `$function` then you need to change your condition from

```
if(!empty($function) && function_exists($function))
```

to

```
if(isset($function) && is_callable($function))
```

Comment: now this is interesting. Let me check that out and try it. and yes I see what you mean, I think it is erroring on the empty call and not the actual function. And yes, as it sets, I cannot use a var since $function in this case is a string and not an actual function.

Comment: @JakeStone How does this answer explain the error message? If `empty($function)` returns `true` then `$function` is not executed but the error message says it is **executed** with the incorrect number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use closures with argument unpacking

```
$closureA = function ($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };
$closureB = function ($a) { return $a * 2; };
$closureC = function () { return 2; };

function run(Closure $closure, array $args = []) {
   return $closure(...$args);
}

echo run($closureA, [1,2]);
echo run($closureB, [2]);
echo run($closureC);
```

**Output:**

342

which is result of running 3 closures with different arguments even with one without args.

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d059aca31ac4bb5cebc776964fc87ec596a29761)

Closures may be set to an array with key as the function name, then easily with array_key_exists you can check if such closure exist and if so then invoke it with run() function

example below:

```
$closures = [];
$closures['add'] = function ($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };
$closures['multiplyby2'] = function ($a) { return $a * 2; };
$closures['return2'] = function () { return 2; };

function run(string $name, array $args = []){
   global $closures;
   return array_key_exists($name, $closures) ? $closures[$name](...$args) : "no closure for given name";
}

echo run('add', [1,2]);
echo run('multiplyby2', [2]);
echo run('return2');
echo run('blabla');
```

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b691055b3b7a8d50ce75b887f409bbcfda93cd0)

Answer (score 0):

Calling variable functions is the job for [callables](http://www.php.net/callable). Despite the PHP/7 enhancements it's pretty old feature. You can use:

- [call_user_func()](http://php.net/call_user_func) is argument count if fixed and you have them in variables.
- [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) in any other case.

Additionally (not sure if you need it here) you can grab all arguments received by a function with [func_get_args()](http://php.net/func_get_args).

Answer (score 0):

From the error message *"Too few arguments to function validate(), 0 passed"* it seems `$function == 'validate'` and `$arg` and `$arg2` are empty. Please note that the PHP function [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) also considers the number `0` and the string `"0"` as empty values.

You should use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check if a variable is an empty string. If you set `$arg` and `$arg2` with values you get from the request then they are strings (they can also be arrays of strings).

A possible rewrite for your code could be:

```
if (is_callable($f)) {
    // Collect all the non-empty arguments in $arguments
    $arguments = [];
    // $arg[0] is the first character of the string stored in $arg
    // when it is set (it exists) the string is not empty
    if (isset($arg[0]) {
        $arguments[] = $arg;
    }
    // More arguments
    if (isset($arg2[0]) {
        $arguments[] = $arg2;
    }

    // Call the function with arguments
    call_user_func_array($f, $arguments);
}
```

Read more about [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php), [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this

```
function test($arg1=FALSE,$arg2=FALSE){ // setting default value

    // If you want to check if the values are numeric or something like that
    // $arg1 = $arg1?is_numeric($arg1)?$arg1:FALSE:FALSE;
    // $arg2 = $arg2?is_numeric($arg2)?$arg2:FALSE:FALSE;
    $bothValid = ($arg1 && $arg2)?TRUE:FALSE;

    // Then you can proceed the way you like
    if($bothValid){
        // code that uses both params
        // return something;
    }

    if($arg1){
        // code that uses argument 1
        // return something;
    }

    if($arg2){
        // code that uses argument 2
        // return something;
    }   
}
```

or similar like below

```
function test($type,$arg1=FALSE,$arg2=FALSE){ // setting default value

    // If you want to check if the values are numeric or something like that
    // $arg1 = $arg1?is_numeric($arg1)?$arg1:FALSE:FALSE;
    // $arg2 = $arg2?is_numeric($arg2)?$arg2:FALSE:FALSE;

    $bothValid = ($arg1 && $arg2)?TRUE:FALSE;
    switch ($type) {
        case ($type == 'add' && $bothValid):
            return $arg1 + $arg2;
        break;

        default:
            return 'Your error message';
        break;
    }
}
```

You can check it by following function calls

```
test();
test(1,2);
test('sdfsdfsf','sdfsdf');
```

Answer (score -2):

Move your functions to class. Then you can simplify your code:

```
class myClass {
    public function foo($arg = null, $arg2 = null) {}

    public function test($function, $arg, $arg2) {
        $args = array_filter([$arg, $arg2]);

        if (method_exists([$this, $function])) {
            if (empty($args) && !empty($_POST)) {
                $function('Hello world');
            } else {
                call_user_func_array([$this, $function], array_filter($args));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is down voted because my OP says do not use OOP in answer. I KNOW OOP works.. I am experimenting with something else. good answer though.